# Using srand(time(NULL)) in Swift gives compiler error

Tags: swift

I'm trying to seed a random number generator in Swift using `srand(time(NULL))`, but I get this compiler error:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'NULL'

Is there another way I should be using srand()?

Answer (score 9):

Swift uses `nil` for a NULL-pointer, and the return value of `time()` has to
be cast to an `UInt32`:

```
srand(UInt32(time(nil)))
```

But consider to use `arc4random()` or its variants instead. From http://nshipster.com/random/:

> - `arc4random` does not require an initial seed (with `srand` or `srandom`), making it that much easier to use.
> - `arc4random` has a range up to 0x100000000 (4294967296), whereas `rand` and `random` top out at RAND_MAX = 0x7fffffff (2147483647).
> - `rand` has often been implemented in a way that regularly cycles low bits, making it more predictable.

For example,

```
let x = arc4random_uniform(10)
```

generates a random number in the range 0 ... 9.

Comment: Thanks, Martin R. You're right arc4random() is probably a better choice. But I'm glad you cleared up srand() for me.

Answer (score 0):

For some compilers this `NULL==0` is not true. We are using `NULL` for pointers. Try this:

```
srand(time(0));
```

Comment: I've tried using srand(time(0)) and get a different error:

Comment: The error is 'time_t' is not convertible to 'UInt32'