# How does one seed the random number generator in Swift?

Tags: random, swift

My app uses random numbers. I would like to seed the random number generator so that it won't be the same every time. How might I go about doing this?

EDIT:

What parameter do I give srand() to seed the random generator with the current time?

Comment: Are you asking how to generate a random number in swift?

Comment: no, just asking how to seed the rand() generator

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007129/how-does-one-generate-a-random-number-in-apples-swift-language

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using srand(time(NULL)) in swift gives compiler error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25610857/using-srandtimenull-in-swift-gives-compiler-error)

Comment: The recommended way of generating random numbers is arc4random_uniform(), which doesn't need to be seeded.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works:

```
let time = UInt32(NSDate().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)
srand(time)
print("Random number: \(rand()%10)")
```

Comment: is there a way to seed with text and get number as result?

Comment: There are lots. One way would be to get the string's unicodeScalars value, iterate over each item in the collection reading its `value` attribute, and perform some kind of mathematical operation to combine them all into one number. You could just add them all together, but that would mean that anagrams of the same string would have the same seed value - play around with it and I'm sure you can come up with a reasonable solution.

Comment: Will that value (NSDate().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate) ever get too big to fit into a UInt32?

Comment: Notice that srand can't be used in Swift3 anymore. You can use srand48 instead.

Comment: `srandom()` and `random()` seem to be preferable.

Comment: this is no longer valid in Swift 5